# Python - Scrapy crawling the web

Tags: python, loops, scrapy

well here is my project/spider , works fine....

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import time

class SccbotakiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SccBotaki'
    start_urls = ['url']
    time.sleep(1)

    def parse(self, response):
        daten = response.css('#daten').extract()
        cartext = response.css('div.car_header > b::text').extract()
        spacerimg = response.css('div.rechts > img::attr(src)').extract()
        inhalt = response.css('div.inhalt')
        prodname = inhalt.css('div.prod-name::text').extract()
        artnr = inhalt.css('div.art-nr > span::text').extract()
        avaible = inhalt.css('div.ampel > img::attr(src)').extract()
        price = inhalt.css('div.preis::text').extract()


        for item in zip(prodname,artnr,avaible,price):
            scraped_info = {
            'prodname' : item[0] ,
            'artnr' : item[1] ,
            'avaible' : item[2] ,
            'price' : item[3] ,
        }
            yield scraped_info
```

check out the url inside of image because i cannot use tiny url inside this post
[URL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55KZO.png)
but i wanted to scrape daten,cartext,spacerimg aswell im gonna get different/bad results 
    btw in settings.py i did like that to export into csv file:

```
    #Export as CSV Feed
    FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
    FEED_URI = "UltraRacing.csv"
```

so, my question is why i cannot scrape like my image when im adding "daten,cartext,spacerimg"?
if i did scrape all of them together im gonna get in csv just 1 row with all of the informations in 1 cell and if ill remove the "daten,cartext,spacerimg from the loop", ill get the perfect results....

hope this make sense...

Comment: post you code instead of images

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `zip` differently sized lists: `prodname`, `artnr`, `avaible`, `price` have 41 elements but `daten` and `cartext` have only 1 element and `spacerimg` is 9 elements.

Comment: what can i do to scrape all of them?

Comment: First you need to understand what output do you want (and show it here)

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/cqx2Y9/unknown.png, on the left is my script and looks perfect dont get me wrong...but on the right side is the elements i wanted to scrape but not like that....and the script looks like that: https://pastebin.com/FrECbC8N, By the way thank you for your answer's, i apreciate that!

Comment: @BaggelisKotsifakhs you need to explain how do you want to match 41 product code elements against 9 image elements

Comment: i wanted to add some if statement's but doesnt work when im doing that... for example " if you dont find any "daten" then give me blank ", i think if ill do that that problem will be sholved